# ndk-gdb and eclipse "No Source File named..."

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, gdb, android-ndk

I'm trying to debug some native code I built using the android ndk-build script and have hit a small hurdle.  I've compiled the native code into a shared library and I want to debug it using ndk-gdb in eclipse.  The code is built using

```
APP_OPTIM := debug
```

in the Application.mk file and I've also added the -g flag just to be sure.

Eclipse is configured to debug the native code and I can connect to the gdbserver on the device but I am unable to set breakpoints due to the following error from gdb:

```
496-break-insert /home/lithium/workspace/supermariowar/jni/SMW/SDL_android_main.cpp:17
No source file named /home/lithium/workspace/supermariowar/jni/SMW/SDL_android_main.cpp.
&"No source file named /home/lithium/workspace/supermariowar/jni/SMW/SDL_android_main.cpp.\n"
496^done
(gdb) 
499-exec-continue
499^running
(gdb)
```

There is indeed a file named SDL_android_main.cpp at the location shown but this is the error I am getting and it will not hit the breakpoint at this time.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

-clark-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error doesn't mean that GDB can't see `/home/lithium/workspace/supermariowar/jni/SMW/SDL_android_main.cpp`. Rather, it means that GDB can't see debug info for that source in the executable and shared libraries *currently* loaded.

It may be that your shared library is not loaded yet.

Or it could be that the file is known to GDB, but under some other name. Try `info sources` or `break SDL_android_main.cpp:17`

Comment: System.loadLibrary() had not been called yet.  You nailed that one on the head.  Thanks!